# Array.length is undefined on data load causing error in react using hooks

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react (and to trying to use Hooks).  I am loading user data and looping through it to create a dashboard list of those users.  When I try to add a badge that returns the number of items associated with a user, user.tasks.length is said to be undefined thus causing an error.

If I remove the .length the client names render successfully.  So I assume the initial data is undefined. I can console.log user.tasks, so it does load. I set up a badge handler with (typeof user.tasks !== 'undefined') but this doesn't re-render after the data loads and only returns the else result (null)?

My data looks like this:

```
ListOfTeam.users = [
{ _id: objectId,
  firstName: string,
  tasks: [array of strings]
]
```

I thought that useEffect re-renders the entire DOM, and would thus re-render this component list.  Does the initial run error ruin any rerenders once the data loads?  Is the badgeHandler the wrong way to think about this?

```
const Dashboard4 = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({})
    const [ListOfTeam, setListOfTeam] = useState({ users: [] })

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/users/me')
            .then(res => {
                setUser({ user: res.data })
            });

    }, [])

     useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
        const result = await 
                   axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/users/userlist/',
            );
            setListOfTeam(result.data)
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [user]);

     const handleBadge = () => {
        if (typeof user.tasks !== 'undefined') {
            return user.tasks.length;
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }

return (
<div> 
  <List>
    {ListOfTeam.users.map(user => {
            return ( 
            <div key={user._id}>
                <Badge badgeContent={handleBadge()} color="primary">
                  <ListItem button >
                     <ListItemIcon>
                       <PeopleIcon />
                        </ListItemIcon>
                     <ListItemText primary={user.firstName} />
                  </ListItem>
                 </Badge>
              </div>);})}
   </List>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Jacob! Please show how your data looks, or ideally  create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by removing the handleBadge() completely, passing {user.tasks.length} directly in the component and rewriting my first useEffect asynchronously in the same form as my second useEffect call. 

i appreciate everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its trying to print the values before the axios request is complete which is where the assignment of data happens. Otherwise, a few things to check:

A) What is the axios request returning? Are you sure that there is a tasks property in there?

B) What is the purpose of Badge badgeContent={handleBadge()}? Remember a number or null is being returned here rather than the user data.

C) As for the handleBadge check, rather than checking as to whether the type is undefined, you should be checking whether it itself is undefined or empty. So I would change this to:

```
if (!user.tasks) {
    return null;
} else {
    return user.tasks.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really familiar with React hooks, but they should be similar to good old fashioned react.

Your async/awaits are all jumbled up and using both promises and async/await doesn't look right, in my opinion.

Just rewrite your effect functions:

```
  useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/users/me');
    setUser({ user: result.data });
  }, [])

   useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api/users/userlist/');
    setListOfTeam(result.data);
  }, [user]);
```

See if this solves your issues.